# why is jtable output is not printing on the paper?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I have populated jtable from database like below.![enter image description here][1]
Now I am trying to send this output to printer.but when i click on print button ,output on the paper is not correct.

I haved used this method.

1.ActionListener

```
btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
            preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);
            //If user does not hit cancel then print.
            if (preformat != postformat) 
            {
                //Set print component
                pjob.setPrintable(new Printer(table), postformat);
                if (pjob.printDialog()) {
                    try {
                        pjob.print();
                    } catch (PrinterException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

2.Printer Class

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
    import java.awt.print.Printable;
    import java.awt.print.PrinterException;

    public class Printer implements Printable {
    final Component comp;

    public Printer(Component comp){
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index) 
            throws PrinterException {
        if (page_index > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }    
        // get the bounds of the component
        Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();    
        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();    
        double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = format.getImageableY();    
        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        comp.paint(g2);    
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @User404 Actually when i click on print button ,printer prints the paper,but jtable data is not reflected on the paper. i.e. output is not correct on the paper

Comment: You know, `JTable` has it's own printable mechanism. Have a ook at [`JTable#print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#print()) and [How to use tables: Printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing)